# How can I say that this model have been used by many people?

Tags: sentence

How can I say that this model have been used by many people?

Is this ok?

> "it has been hugely used before"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though our president might say it that way, it is not idiomatic.

*It has been widely used by others in the field.*

*Many previous projects made use of this model.*

Comment: Not the Queen's English?